# I should have checked out from another branch in Git, how do I fix it?

Tags: git

I created a feature branch from master but I should have done it from develop branch how can I fix it?

For visualization I've done this:

```
          D---E---F develop
         /
A---B---C master
         \
          G---H feature
```

but I should have done this:

```
                    G---H feature
                   /
          D---E---F develop
         /
A---B---C master
```

I haven't tried anything, I am not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 2):

This is a text-book example of using `git rebase`, assuming you haven't brushed `feature` yet.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase develop
```

Comment: Or as a single command: `git rebase develop feature`

Comment: Just as I was too lazy to test this, I was too lazy to lookup the order of the arguments for that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply done by re-creating all commits of `feature` on top of `develop`. A command which can do this, is [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase --onto develop master feature
```

- Take all commits between head commit of `master` (exclusive) and head commit of `feature` (inclusive)
- Recreate them on top of the `develop` branch

Note that re-creating commits are independent of the old commits and they will be assigned a new commit id/hash. If the history is already shared with others, it shouldn't be altered, unless absolutely necessary. Rewritten history also needs to be force-pushed, because the ref on the remote server cannot be fast-forwarded.

To get the changes of `develop` without rewriting history, simply use `git merge` to bring both histories together:

```
git checkout feature
git merge develop
```

Comment: Is `--onto` necessary? (Clearly, I haven't tested either your answer or mine.)

Comment: @chepner no, in this case it is not necessary and a simple `git rebase develop feature` would work too. But I like to be explicit and using `--onto` makes sure that the commits are picked exactly as specified.